# Disable msvsmon timeout from the command line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I'm doing remote debugging regularly thanks to Visual Studio 2010's msvsmon tool. I used to set the timeout to zero in the options screen, as I just want the tool to keep running until I'm done with it:

[image]

This works fine, but I grew tired of doing this everyday and I'm trying to do it from a script, using the appropriate command line switch:

```
msvsmon.exe /timeout:0
```

But no cigar:

[image]

I can work around this by setting a ridiculously long timeout, but I'm just checking: is there a proper way to disable this timeout from the command line? Or maybe with a registry key?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well if there's no proper way, I guess the best is just to use the maximum allowed, which seems to be the maximum of a signed integer, minus one:

```
msvsmon.exe /timeout:2147483646
```

That leaves more than 68 years of remote debugging, should be enough for me!

Answer (score -1):

As follows from this kb article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.71).aspx, using -timeout -1 should prevent the connection from breaking on timeout; however I didn't have a chance to verify that myself.

Comment: This seems to be for VS2003 and msvcmon. This gives an "Invalid command line argument." for VS2010 msvsmon. Shame, but thanks for searching, this might help VS2003 users ;)